# Why does the event listener only register on the last element created in for loop?

Tags: javascript, html, for-loop, event-handling, innerhtml

I am creating checkboxes using JavaScript, adding the `onchange` listener to them and adding them to a div using a loop. However, only the last checkbox has the event listener registered.

Why is this happening?

```js
var div = document.getElementById("mydiv");
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    div.innerHTML += ("<br>" + i);
    var input = document.createElement("input");
    input.type = "checkbox";
    input.onchange = function() {
      alert("foo");
    };
    div.appendChild(input);
}
```

```html
<div id="mydiv"></div>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Appending to `div` using the `Element.innerHTML` property removes the existing event handlers because it is really doing this...

```
div.innerHTML = (div.innerHTML + '<br>' + i);
```

So it completely rewrites the HTML and all event handlers are lost.

Use `Document.createElement()` and `Document.createTextNode()` instead.

```js
var div = document.getElementById("mydiv");
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    div.appendChild(document.createElement('br'));
    div.appendChild(document.createTextNode(i));
    var input = document.createElement("input");
    input.type = "checkbox";
    input.onchange = function() {
      alert("foo");
    };
    div.appendChild(input);
}
```

```html
<div id="mydiv"></div>
```